# Are infrared jammers possible, and how would they work?

Tags: thermodynamics, infrared-radiation, technology

In the C-64 game *Gunship*, the player can escape both radar-guided and heatseeking missiles. For the radar ones, he can use a physical countermeasure - chaff - as well as an electronic one - a radar jammer, I presume. For the heatseekers, the physical tool is flares. But the game also offers an "electronic" infrared jammer. Does such a thing exist? And if so, how does it work?

One possibility is that the jammer creates a heat bloom that fools the missile - but if so, couldn't the missile simply focus on the center of the bloom, and then trigger a magnetic fuse or a proximity one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are emitting infra red radiation, there is no "anti infra red" electronic jammer to block your body heat, say.

You could wear an ice packed jacket, that would absorb the radiation, or get into the middle of a hotter area, such as  a fire,  to be obscured, but neither are good options.

It also depends on the sensitivity of the device picking up  your radiation.

Getting inside a building, especially a warm one, is probably your best option, or digging a rather large hole in the ground.

What military  aircraft usually do, as I am sure you know, is fire off very hot flares and hope that  heat seeking missiles target the flare, rather than head straight towards  the hot exhaust fumes of the engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've always wondered this myself, and anytime the topic comes up, I refer back to a conversation I had with a C-17 Globemaster III pilot. I approached him and pointed out a sensor on the back of his aircraft, asking him if it was like a back up camera, or that it might be a camera used to observe cargo or troops being dropped out the rear cargo door. The image attached was what I was pointing to.

[image]

The same sensor is on each side of the rear of the fuselage. The pilot said that the direct answer was classified, but he could say that it was a part of the Countermeasure system. My best guess is that its a laser that can track and interfere with the seeker head of IR missiles.

Answer (score 0):

"Electronic" infrared countermeasures have existed since the Vietnam war. Current designs are indeed turreted and have to train their energy on the incoming missile. [Northrop Grumman even shows at least one off on their website!](https://www.northropgrumman.com/what-we-do/air/an-aaq-24v-dircm-directional-infrared-countermeasure/) While details are obviously classified for the time being, it's stated they overwhelm the sensors in the missile. Whether that's true I don't know.

If it's possible to misdirect the missile, or just make it go straight while you maneuver away isn't clear and likely to be dangerous knowledge.

Comment: Yes, that is probably true. The problem is that this only works for "dumb" missiles. A modern one has multiple sensors and effective algorithms to counteract the jamming of one or several of them. Escaping a modern air-defense system has become increasingly unlikely for piloted aircraft.